# My custom Vercel domain creates a 403 error

Tags: git, next.js, vercel

I'm new with Vercel and it seems like I'm the only one with this problem.

I imported a GitHub repository and created a project in Vercel. I have added a custom domain which is accepted by Vercel (I followed the given instructions and modified the DNS configuration)

When I access this custom domain, I have a 403 error.

The auto generated domains work, but not mine. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double check that your domains were properly added to Vercel. You can check it in your settings under the domains tab - `https://vercel.com/{username}/{project}/settings/domains`. It should look something like this:
[image: validconfig]

I would try removing the domain name then adding it back to Vercel.

Vercel will either tell you to add a type `A` record:

```
Type     Name      Value
A        @         76.76.21.21
```

[image: type A record]

Or a `CNAME` record if you are setting a subdomain:

```
Type     Name             Value
CNAME    [subdomain]      cname.vercel-dns.com
```

[image: CNAME record]

Vercel also has a page called "[Why is my Vercel domain not verified?](https://vercel.com/support/articles/why-is-my-vercel-domain-unverified)
" which may help.

And finally you can point your name servers to Vercel which will allow you to set your domain name.
[image: Vercel nameservers]

The only thing I was able to find on the Vercel documentation that mentions a `403` error is this page "[I'm seeing 403 Forbidden responses](https://vercel.com/docs/integrations#using-the-vercel-api/common-errors/i-m-seeing-403-forbidden-responses)."